# pyui4c VS import file.ui

Tags: python, qt, pyuic

Until now, I have been developing my GUIs by creating the user interface with QtDesigner, saving the file as `file.ui` and using `pyuic4` to create the `file.py`.

However, quite recently I have read that it is not necessary to create the `file.py`. I can just load the `file.ui` by doing :

```
class MyWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('file.ui', self)
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This might work, it actually works because I have tested it.

My questions are:

1- Is this way better than the other or not? and why?

2- If I use this seccond option, how do I make the connections of the buttons, event etc?